# mySQL query is not working properly

Tags: mysql

What's wrong with my query:

```
SELECT
    Articles.Name, 
    GroupOfArticles.Name, 
    (select GroupOfArticles.Name from GroupOfArticles
     where GroupOfArticles.ParentGroup= Articles.Group)
FROM Articles
JOIN GroupOfArticles
    ON Articles.Group = GroupOfArticles.ID
```

I want to show the name of the article and the name of the most basic group in the hierarchy...

[databasemodel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jknzw.jpg)

Comment: Can you show some data for the two tables in your actual question, along with the expected output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Obviously I haven't seen your schema, but I don't believe you need the sub-select at all. It appears that it would return the same as `GroupOfArticles.Name` does?

```
SELECT 
   Articles.Name, 
   GroupOfArticles.Name 
FROM 
    Articles JOIN GroupOfArticles 
        ON Articles.Group = GroupOfArticles.ID 
            AND GroupOfArticles.ParentGroup = Articles.Group
```

Actually, the above assumes that every article returned will be part of a specific group, and will also have a parent group which is the same. [Inception](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inception)?

**EDIT** Based on more requirements / information, here is a second version:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    a.Name, 
    g.Name 
FROM 
    GroupOfArticles g INNER JOIN GroupOfArticles g1 
        ON g1.ParentGroup = g.ID
        INNER JOIN Articles a ON
            CASE 
                WHEN g.ParentGroup IS NULL THEN g.ID
                ELSE g1.ID
            END
```

I also created an [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/88503/2) for the above.

**EDIT 2** An alternative version which doesn't include `JOIN` OR `CASE`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    a.Name, 
    g.Name 
FROM 
    Articles a, GroupOfArticles g, GroupOfArticles g1
WHERE 
        g.ID <> g1.ID 
    AND g.ParentGroup IS NULL 
    AND 
    ( 
           a.Group = g.ID
        OR a.Group = g1.ID AND g1.ParentGroup = g.ID
    )
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/88503/4)

Note that in the two latest queries, you could replace the `DISTINCT` keyword with `GROUP BY a.Name HAVING COUNT(*) > 0`, If you really must use those constructs as well. Just remove `DISTINCT` from the top, and add the `GROUP BY ...` at the end.

Comment: According to your supplied image, you want the Article name, and the name / description of (the Group it is part of, if that group has no parent, OR the Parent Group, again if that group has no parent, OR ...).

Comment: If I am correct, then your required output should include: `Merix - For washing clothes` and `Duli - For washing clothes`. If this is not correct, then you need to provide the actual business rules you are working with.

Comment: Yes... see above. Please note that writing joins without using the `JOIN` keyword is not a great idea. It works, but you need to know what you are doing, and readability / portability is not as good as when using `JOIN`s.

Answer (score 1):

You need to JOIN the subquery outside of the actual subquery like

```
SELECT a.Name, g.Name, 
FROM Articles a
INNER JOIN (select Name,ParentGroup from GroupOfArticles) g
   ON g.ID         =a.Group
  AND g.ParentGroup=a.group
```

The actual query shown can even be done without the subquery, like

```
SELECT a.Name, g.Name, 
FROM Articles a
INNER JOIN GroupOfArticles g
   ON g.ID         =a.Group
  AND g.ParentGroup=a.group
```

Although I doubt very much that you *really* want to join on *both* columns: `ID` and `ParentGroup`?